# Combining acspline with filledcurve on data

Tags: gnuplot, bezier, curve, spline, smoothing

I know how to use `filledcurve` with `using 1:2:3` to fill the area between the curves described by columns 2 and 3.

I also know how to smooth a single curve using acsplines with `using 1:2:(0.1)` (with `0.1` being the smoothing weight for each point).

But I fail to combine the two, i.e. fill the area between two smoothed curves.  All variants I try give me error messages like `duplicated or contradicting arguments in datafile options`.

This is what I tried:

```
plot 'datafile' using 1:2:3:(0.1):(0.1) smooth acs with lines
plot 'datafile' using 1:2:(0.1):3:(0.1) smooth acs with lines
```

Is this combination possible at all?  How is the syntax then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can't combine `smooth acspline` and `with filledcurves`, but I also don't know why this shouldn't be possible.
Well, as a workaround, plot your `smooth acspline` curve into a data table first and then plot it `with filledcurves`.

**Code:**

```
### filled acspline curve
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1 2
2 4
3 3
4 1
EOD

# plot your acspline data into a table
set table $ACSpline
    plot $Data u 1:2 smooth acspline
unset table

set style fill transparent solid 0.1 

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "black" ti "Original data", \
     $Data u 1:2 smooth acspline lw 2 lc rgb "red" ti "acspline", \
     $ACSpline u 1:2 w filledcurves x1 lc rgb "red" ti "acspline filled"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

There is another way to get data into a table. Check `help set print`.
With this, you can get the data of the two splines into one datablock and can plot the area between them. Maybe someone knows a simpler way to achieve this.

**Code:**

```
### filled curve between two acsplines
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1 2 4
2 4 1
3 3 0
4 1 3
EOD

# plot your acspline data into tables
set table $ACSpline1
    plot $Data u 1:2:(1) smooth acspline
unset table
set table $ACSpline2
    plot $Data u 1:3:(1) smooth acspline
unset table
set print $BetweenSplines
    do for [i=1:|$ACSpline1|] {
        print sprintf("%s %s %s",word($ACSpline1[i],1),word($ACSpline1[i],2),word($ACSpline2[i],2))
    }
set print

set style fill transparent solid 0.5 

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "black" ti "Original data col 2", \
     $Data u 1:3 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "blue" ti "Original data col 3", \
     $ACSpline1 u 1:2 w l lw 2 lc rgb "red" ti "acspline col 2", \
     $ACSpline2 u 1:2 w l lw 2 lc rgb "green" ti "acspline col 3", \
     $BetweenSplines u 1:2:3 w filledcurves lc rgb "yellow" ti "acspline filled"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Very interesting indeed (I didn't know this table feature).  But … How can I use this to fill the area between *two* curves?  You only fill the area between *one* curve and an axis.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully enough. You want it filled **between two acsplines curves**. Hmm, somehow you need to get the smoothed data into two columns of **one** datablock. I'm sure there is a way. I need to think about it.

Comment: This solution is a little hacky but works!  (I'd prefer something easier to understand for having maintainable code.)  Especially, because my X coordinates are datetimes in a specific format, I need to make sure that printing the time is done in the same format as it is parsed in, and generating the table (datablock) adds doublequotes around the datetimes(!) which is removed again by the printing.  But after figuring out all this, it worked!  Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: glad to hear that in the end it somehow works for you. Well, the datetime is an information which I haven't had until now. gnuplot people (on Linux) tend to use external tools to (re-)arrange or process data, but as long as you can do it with gnuplot I prefer a platform-independent gnuplot-only solution.

Comment: Yeah.  That datetime stuff should be more transparent.  Who would have guessed that it makes a difference whether I'm using datetimes or simple numbers? ;-)